# How to get more than one model object in Spring boot Controller

Tags: spring-boot

I'm a spring newbie. I'm doing this spring-boot project where I have 2 tables for users viz user and user_details. I've made 2 models corresponding to the tables.

When the client fills up the user form, the data for both the user model and user_details model are coming from a same stream. In such a case, how do I handle 2 data models in the controller?

A case for getting a single model object, the controller function would be:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value= "/user")
public void add(@RequestBody User user)  {
// do stuffs on model
   }
```

How do we address the issue if we have to catch user and user_details object both from this very controller?

Comment: create a new model(which has both user and user_details data) solely for the purpose of accepting data from frontend. Then in you controller, you can split this model to user and user details

Comment: An HTTP request can have only one body. So you'll have to create a new POJO that contains all model objects.

Comment: Just remove @RequestBody and bind both objects.